# React native how to refresh basket count

Tags: react-native, mobx, asyncstorage

Hi everyone I'm trying to make an app which has basket. I made it with React-native , Mobx and AsyncStorage

When someones click add to basket to an item it add its to AsyncStorage then counts the basket count with another function. Thats all works fine but when I'm in the products page and select add to basket to an item. Basket count is not changing untill I press to another page.

Summary I gotta re-render tabbar when this metod calls. Thank you

Add function

```
@action async AddproductToBasket(product, Count) {
    try { 
      const con = {product, Count};
      const tempProduct = [];

      await AsyncStorage.getItem('basket').then((basket) => {
       
        console.log(basket);
        tempProduct.push(con);
        if (basket) {
          tempProduct.push(...JSON.parse(basket));
        }

        this.basketCount = tempProduct.length;
      });

      await AsyncStorage.setItem('basket', JSON.stringify(tempProduct));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

Count

```
@observable basketCount = 0;


@action async basketCount() {
    try {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('basket').then((basket) => {
          const tempBasket = [];
          if (basket) {
            tempBasket.push(...JSON.parse(basket));
          }          
      runInAction(() => {
          this.basketCount = tempBasket.length;
       
      });         
        });      
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

Also this is my tabbar

```
function TabBar({state, descriptors, navigation}) {

  var Count = AuthStore.basketCount;
  return (
    <Box
      pb={20}
      bg="white"
      flexDirection="row"
      style={{
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOpacity: 0.1,
        shadowRadius: 20,
      }}>
      {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
        const {options} = descriptors[route.key];

        const label =
          options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
            ? options.tabBarLabel
            : options.title !== undefined
            ? options.title
            : route.name;

        const isFocused = state.index === index;

        const onPress = () => {
          const event = navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabPress',
            target: route.key,
          });         
                       if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
            
            navigation.navigate(route.name);
          }
        };
        return label === 'Main' ? (
          <Box
            key={label}
            p={15}
            mt={-38}
            bg={'menuBgColor'}
            style={{shadowColor: 'green'}}
            borderColor="red"
            borderRadius="full">
            <Button size={60} bg="#053EA1" borderRadius="full" onPress={onPress}>
             (
                <TabOrtaFocusedSVG
                  color={isFocused ? theme.colors.red : theme.colors.textLight}
                />
              ) 
            </Button>
          </Box>
        ) : (
          // tab-button
          <Button
            key={label}
            pt={6}
            flexDirection="column"
            height={56}
            flex={1}
            onPress={onPress}>
            {label === 'Main2' && (
              <Tabmenu1
                color={isFocused ? theme.colors.red : theme.colors.textLight}
              />
            )}           

            {label === 'Basket' && (
              <Box
                position="absolute"
                top={10}
                right={10}
                height={20}
                width={20}
                borderRadius={400}
                bg="#FF1616"
                justifyContent="center"
                alignItems="center">
                <Text>{Count}</Text>
              </Box>
            )}

            {/* indicator */}
            <Box
              size={4}
              bg={isFocused ? 'red' : 'white'}
              mt={6}
              borderRadius="full"
            />
          </Button>
        );
      })}
    </Box>
  );
}

export default TabBar;
```

PACKAGES

```
"mobx": "^6.1.4",
"mobx-react": "^7.1.0",
"popup-ui": "^1.2.2",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might overwriting this.basketCount in the AddproductToBasket function.

you must have a try to increase the old value with the new value of the basketCount

like:

```
this.basketCount += tempProduct.length;
```

Also, Have a try by adding the observer in the TabBar Component to listen the mobx state updates like below:

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite" // Or "mobx-react".

const TabBar = observer(({state, descriptors, navigation}) => {

  var Count = AuthStore.basketCount;
  return (
    <Box
      pb={20}
      bg="white"
      flexDirection="row"
      style={{
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOpacity: 0.1,
        shadowRadius: 20,
      }}>
      {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
        const {options} = descriptors[route.key];

        const label =
          options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
            ? options.tabBarLabel
            : options.title !== undefined
            ? options.title
            : route.name;

        const isFocused = state.index === index;

        const onPress = () => {
          const event = navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabPress',
            target: route.key,
          });         
                       if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
            
            navigation.navigate(route.name);
          }
        };
        return label === 'Main' ? (
          <Box
            key={label}
            p={15}
            mt={-38}
            bg={'menuBgColor'}
            style={{shadowColor: 'green'}}
            borderColor="red"
            borderRadius="full">
            <Button size={60} bg="#053EA1" borderRadius="full" onPress={onPress}>
             (
                <TabOrtaFocusedSVG
                  color={isFocused ? theme.colors.red : theme.colors.textLight}
                />
              ) 
            </Button>
          </Box>
        ) : (
          // tab-button
          <Button
            key={label}
            pt={6}
            flexDirection="column"
            height={56}
            flex={1}
            onPress={onPress}>
            {label === 'Main2' && (
              <Tabmenu1
                color={isFocused ? theme.colors.red : theme.colors.textLight}
              />
            )}           

            {label === 'Basket' && (
              <Box
                position="absolute"
                top={10}
                right={10}
                height={20}
                width={20}
                borderRadius={400}
                bg="#FF1616"
                justifyContent="center"
                alignItems="center">
                <Text>{Count}</Text>
              </Box>
            )}

            {/* indicator */}
            <Box
              size={4}
              bg={isFocused ? 'red' : 'white'}
              mt={6}
              borderRadius="full"
            />
          </Button>
        );
      })}
    </Box>
  );
}
})

export default TabBar;
```

Comment: Sadly nothing changed also tryed  this.basketCount = 0;  this.basketCount += tempBasket.length;

Comment: No, again you are overwriting the value by this.basketCount = 0;

Comment: But tempProduct.length; is whole basket length

Comment: Also that way is not made different. Tab-bar is not refreshing until navigaiting to another screen

Comment: @masterAvatarr Check Updated Answer

Comment: I couldn't make it

Comment: Try to change the code I am providing in my answer.

Comment: Very sadly nothing changed but navigating page

Comment: Thank you for your try but I still could not make it

Comment: Which package you are using for the mobx ?

Comment: I added to bottom

Comment: Please refer to the official docs to figure out the issue as now it seems alright in the code or tries to debug the code. refer to https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html

Comment: Well thank you again for your patience and effort. I will search